# Cassandra node self-removal

Tags: cassandra

I run Cassandra 3.1 in autoscaling group. Recently one of the machines failed and got replaced. I did not lose any data, but client applications were trying to connect to a node which was marked down.

I am looking for a way to gracefully remove a node from a cluster with a *quick* command which I would invoke via systemd right before it shuts down cassandra during the shutdown process.

`nodetool decommission` involves data streaming and takes long time.

`nodetool removenode` and `nodetool assassinate` can't remove the node they are running at.

- Losing data is not my concern. My goal is fully automated node replacement.
- Fixing client libaries is out of scope of this question

Comment: why not simply shutdown machine & call removenode from other?

Comment: Have you looked at the replace_address_first_boot method of replacing nodes? It doesn't cover use cases where you want to scale down (I'd go with Alex's suggestion for that, if you don't care about possibly losing data), but will be much more efficient in cases like the one you describe where the instance gets replaced. http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html#replacing-a-dead-node

Comment: Thanks guys. @AlexOtt : that's what i'm doing right now and i am looking for a way to automate it

Comment: @JustinCameron In this case I have to know the address of a failed node before I start cassandra on a fresh machine. I will go with this option if I find no way to run "quickly deregister myself" command from a node that it being shut down.

Comment: The best way you can just down the node and remove the node by removenode or command. you can also use assassinate  if you don't concern for data.